# Boost run-time error

Tags: boost

Подскажите, что может быть. Компиляция, "линковка" проходят нормально. Из под IDE прога заускается и отрабатывает отлично. А при запуске приложения вываливается "мессага" run-time error. Как для работы с filesystem так и с thread. Пробовал -static и подкладывать dll в папку с exe. Результат один и тот же. Программа самая элементарная, тестовая.

```
#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    fs::path full_path( fs::initial_path<fs::path>() );
    full_path = fs::system_complete( fs::path( argv[0] ) );
    std::cout << full_path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какая именно ошибка? Вы пробовали оттрассировать? Какая строка валится?

Comment: скомпилил такой строкой

   g++ c.cpp  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

все нормально запускается и работает.

Comment: Вопрос решен! В общем пока не знаю что было, но сменил boost с 55 на 54 (собрал). Все стало работать отлично. IDE (линковщик, компилятор) настроены. Спасибо!

Comment: возможно, что у Вас были разные (несогласованные) версии dll.